# Tab drop for Bootstrap - if one of the tab element has dropdown it breaks on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When you use `nav-tabs` and if one element (tab) has dropdown and you start resizing the window it works fine at the start, but if you drag to make the window larger again the items from the dropdown will appear on the same row with the other tabs. The dropdown get empty from that moment. As much as you resize the window it stays the same. Check the example from here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4neLL6kq/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tab 5</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tab 6</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown Tab <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas how can I fix this? I want the dropdown to remain a dropdown when the element moves under the tabdrop.

**UPDATE**
Printscreen with the tabdrop and without. The right way is with tabdrop, but it has some problems in the way is working.

**with tabdrop**
[image: with tabdrop]

**without tabdrop**
[image: without tabdrop]

Answer (score 0):

It has been 2 years since this question asked but I will answer.

Your problem is that you are adding the dropdown in your HTML manually.
TabDrop.JS creates the dropdown such a way that it does not make this problem.
In TabDrop.JS dropdown is created as the first element of the navtabs and pushed right for a good reason, it always appends to the dropdown or the navtabs. Since you created the dropdown as a last element manually you are having this problem.
Remove the dropdown from your html and add all the elements as nav items normally.
You also need to include popper.js in order to see the dropdown contents.

HTML should be:

```js
$('.nav-tabs').tabdrop()
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tab 5</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tab 6</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

This code is enough to implement `nav-tabs`. Use `data-toggle = "tab"` to toggle between tabs. Remove the script that you have used in you fiddle and your `nav-tab` is up and running properly.

**JS**

```
$('.nav-tabs').tabdrop()
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs  nav-pills">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab 5</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab 6</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true">
      Dropdown Tab <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">item 1</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">item 2</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4neLL6kq/4/)**

Comment: nope.... So, I want the tabdrop to work, but is not working properly when you have a dropdown as a tab item.

Comment: In order to call tabdrop you just need to call `$('.nav-tabs').tabdrop()` and nothing else. I think the updated fiddle works as you want.

Comment: please check the print screens that I added in the initail question, below UPDATE. That is not responsive as I want. The Tabdrop that I need is creating a dropdown when the screen is too small to fit all the tabs in one row, and instead putting them one after the other on 2 or more rows that script moves them under a dropdown. Check the exmaple from my fiddler